# VBA Conditional concatenate of a group of cells in two columns

Tags: vba, excel

This is far to advanced for me to figure out. 
Here is an example of the worksheet layout:

```
Row#    ColA    ColB                                 
23      7       Description 
24      8       Description 
25      
26              For cases with  
27              SpecialOptionDesc = Yes
28      9       Description 
29      
30              For cases with  
31              SomeOptionDesc = Yes
32              and 
33              AnotherOptionDesc = No
34      9       Description 
35      
36      10      Description
```

I'm need to consolidate the information in ColB when the them "For cases with" appears, with the cells below it. The information needs to end up on the row that has the identifying number in ColA. So in this case ColB Rows 26, 27, 28, will all be "copied" or whatever into ColB row 28. Likewise, ColB Rows 30 though 34 will all be on ColB row 34. The old rows (26, 27, 30, 31, 33) can be deleted mashed together or whatever. No data on those rows will be needed any longer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't actually compile this and try it Excel, but I think that it will get you 90% of the way there if not all the way.  I am stepping away from the computer for a bit, but will do some testing when I get back.

```
Dim cellValue As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim strResult As String

Const endRow As Integer = 500

For i = 1 To endRow
     If LCase(ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 2).Value) = "for cases with" Then
        j = 0
        strResult = ""

        While ActiveSheet.Cells(i + j, 1).Value = "" And i + j < endRow
            strResult = strResult + " " + ActiveSheet.Cells(i + j, 2).Value

            ' delete stuff after using
            ActiveSheet.Cells(i + j, 2).Value = ""

            j = j + 1
        Wend

        ActiveSheet.Cells(i + j, 2) = strResult + " " + ActiveSheet.Cells(i + j, 2)
     End If
Next i
```

Comment: I edited the line `ActiveSheet.Cells(i + j - 1, 2) = strResult` to remove the `- 1`.  It seems to be working as requested now.

Comment: It's still not working for me and I don't understand why. Is there anything else that I could provide to help?

Comment: What is the problem you are having with it?   How are you running it?

Comment: With the courser in the Sub and hitting F5, like I do all the time. I tryed running it step by step and I see it highlight Sub & title, then For `For i = 1 To endRow` then If `LCase(ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 2).Value) = "for cases with"` then `End If`. Perhaps my example is not clear enough. Can I get you a copy of one of my sheets perhaps?

Comment: Well the first time through the loop that should happen since it doesn't have "for cases with".  But if it is happening all 500 times through the loop then that means that the `if` condition is failing to find any "for cases with".  Are the descriptions in column B of the spreadsheet?  If not, you will need to change the 2 in every call to `.Cells` to represent the column they are actually in.  Also, I see your records start at 23 in your example.  If that is true of the spreadsheet too, you will want to change `i = 1` to `i = 23`.

Comment: If you figure out why the code doesnt find "for cases with" the rest of the code will work perfectly.

Comment: Yes, it is in column B. The example that I posted is just a section of one of the spread sheets that the "for cases with" scenario is appearing. It could appear from row 1 to row 500 but always in Column B.

Comment: I didn't have my files with me so I just recreated the example and it worked perfectly. I'll have to double check the originals to see what extra little goodies must be hiding in it and messing it up. I'll check in the morning.

Comment: It should be adding a space in this line: `strResult = strResult + " " + ActiveSheet.Cells(i + j, 2).Value`.  If you want it to add more space, just add more space to the empty string in after `strResult +`.

Comment: Oops, one other thing. It's completely overwriting the description. I need to keep that at the end.

Comment: Where do you want to stick the result then? You said to remove unneeded parts of the string and put the result next to the number...where should I stick it if you want to keep the description?

Comment: I'm sorry, another way I might say it is that all needs to be combined into the description cell, with the description. It's ok if the old data remains because I can delete rows with uneeded info later.

Comment: Part of the results need to include the description row. Like my question states in the example, rows 30 through 34 need to all be on row 34. I am sorry if I was unclear with my original question but this is a very important piece of information than needs to be included. I am very thankful for your assistance.

Comment: I edited my response to include the description.  If you want description at the beginning instead of the end of the line just replace the last line with `ActiveSheet.Cells(i + j, 2) = ActiveSheet.Cells(i + j, 2) + " " + strResult`

Comment: Ah, beautiful. Thank you so much for your help and time with this!