# Excel - Macro to merge values into one column, based on unique repeated field

Tags: excel, vba

How do I get a macro to get to do merge all the cells on column B, based on the fact that they have the same value on the cells of column A?

```
**email**           **links**
email1@mail.com value1
email1@mail.com value2
email2@mail.com value3
email2@mail.com value4
email2@mail.com value5
email3@mail.com value5
email3@mail.com value6
```

into this:

```
**email**           **links**
email1@mail.com value1, value2
email2@mail.com value3, value4, value5
email3@mail.com value5, value7
```

Any help will be much appreciated. Please note that I am not an expert on excel, doing my first steps.

Comment: Not a duplicate as in the other one I was hoping for a non-macro alternative. In this case I want a macro.

Answer (score 2):

If it has to be done in macro: 
Google returned several options here's one.
[VBA Conditional concatenate of a group of cells in two columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9134557/vba-conditional-concatenate-of-a-group-of-cells-in-two-columns)
however this can be done without a macro in a few easy steps and formula's... Here's how

In this first step I setup values like you have I ten had D=A and in E entered the formula listed

[image]

I then entered in column F: the following formula in F2 `=IF(LEN(E3)<LEN(E2),"X","")`
I then used filters to filter on X.
Resulting in:
[image]

From here we could copy and paste D/E to a new sheet if needed